# Как разделить контент на 2 части?

Tags: html, css

Есть сайт http://educationmm.shn-host.ru/
Хочу разделить в нем разделить контент на 2 части,
один - на сам контент, второй - на сайд бар.
У меня почему-то при разделении сайд бар появляется в углу контента,
помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Попробуйте вот что: http://csstemplater.com/

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/layout

Comment: Ничего из этого мне, к сожалению, не подходит. :(

Comment: @k0stik0v как такое вообще возможно?

Comment: @inferusvv, ну, я, короче, хотел расписать, почему у меня не получается, но напишу просто то, что руки не из того места растут.

Comment: @k0stik0v, ну, если вы ожидаете получить адекватный ответ, то лучше, конечно, расписать.)

Comment: @k0stik0v, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

html

```
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#content{
float:left;
}
#sidebar{
float:right;
}
```

Comment: Вообще плохое решение. Тогда уже сначала sidebar, ему float left и ширину задать. А у контента margin-left равный или больший ширине сайдбара.